# Why is it called a gas gauge?

Tags: gauge, gas

Why are battery monitor ICs such as STC3115 ([datasheet](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00066800.pdf)) called a gas gauge? This name seems pretty illogical and I was wondering the reasoning/story behind it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it's derived from the American term for vehicle fuel being referred to as gas. Many countries refer to it as fuel or petrol. The Wikipedia article [Fuel gauge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_gauge) starts off with the following:

> A fuel gauge (or gas gauge) is an instrument used to indicate the level of fuel contained in a tank

So I guess from that point of view it makes sense, when a car runs out of gas / fuel it will no longer operate and the same applies to a battery.

Comment: It'll start making sense again when people start using fuel-cells.

Comment: I do wish Americans wouldn't use "gas" like that. [Gas is a physical state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas), and by the way that state isn't a liquid like "gas". I wish they would use the proper word "[Gasoline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gasoline)" like they actually mean. It saves so much confusion with people that speak proper English.

Comment: @Majenko Right...because only American English has homonyms.

Comment: "gas" for "gasoline" is an abbreviation, not a homonym.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39778/why-does-gasoline-have-the-word-gas-in-it-if-its-never-gaseous

Comment: This comment thread gives me gas.